# firebase toDoApp with "value" or child events?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to create a simple ToDoApplication but I am not quite sure if I should use "value" or child's event for that. Any suggestions?

This is what I have written so far:

```
const list1 = document.querySelector('.t__tasks');
const input = document.querySelector('.t__text');
const addBtn = document.querySelector('.t__submit');

const toDoRefObject = firebase.database().ref().child('t');

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ( e ) => {      
    toDoRefObject.on( 'value', data => {
        data.forEach( ( data ) => {
            const li = document.createElement('li');
            const button = document.createElement('button');
            button.classList.add('t__add');
            button.textContent = "Delete";
            button.type = "button";
            li.textContent = data.val();
            li.appendChild(button);
            list1.appendChild(li);
        })          
    });
});

const removeTask = ( e ) => {
    if( !e.target.matches('.t__add') ) return;
}

const addTask = ( ) => {
    const taskText = input.value;
    list1.innerHTML = '';
    toDoRefObject.push(taskText);
};

addBtn.addEventListener('click', addTask);
list1.addEventListener('click', removeTask);
```

and I don't know how to use DOM to remove a single task

Answer (score 2):

Value:

> The value event is used to read a static snapshot of the contents at a given database path, as they existed at the time of the read event. It is triggered once with the initial data and again every time the data changes. The event callback is passed a snapshot containing all data at that location, including child data. In the code example above, value returned all of the blog posts in your app. Everytime a new blog post is added, the callback function will return all of the posts.

Child Added:

> The child_added event is typically used when retrieving a **list** of items from the database. Unlike value which returns the entire contents of the location, child_added is triggered once for each existing child and then again every time a new child is added to the specified path. The event callback is passed a snapshot containing the new child's data. For ordering purposes, it is also passed a second argument containing the key of the previous child.

It does not matter that much as both events will do the required job, usually `child` events is used on lists and since its a `todo` application then I guess you will have a list of todo items, then its probably better to use `child` events to be able to control removing and adding of children easier.

For more info check this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data